# Finding location using google API in mvc 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

i want of find location based on current URL request for my project.
eg. if a user log in , system should output local area -> City -> country
from google API and also show the locaton and google map.

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how you tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us exactly what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See also the help pages (linked at the top of every page) for how to write a good question.

Comment: "i want of find location based on current URL request for my project" - This makes no sense. Location is not dependent on what URL is being visited. That said, what Google API? There's only like 50 different ones they offer. Google Maps API, perhaps? Even then, you don't *retrieve* a location from Google Maps API. It only lets you map addresses and locations you already have. Perhaps you're looking for the HTML 5 Geolocation functionality? See: http://diveintohtml5.info/geolocation.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have worked with freegeoip and to get the geo location from this is as below.

URL:- http://freegeoip.net/xml/{ip}

In this you can provide your IP and can see result in browser.

Implementation in code.

```
string apiUrl = http://freegeoip.net/xml/{ip}

HttpClient HttpClient = new HttpClient();

var response = HttpClient.GetAsync(apiUrl).Result;

if (response != null && response.ReasonPhrase != "Unauthorized")
 {
   var myobject = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

 }
```